# Multiple integrals identity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve a problem from my homework and I am one step away of getting it done. Let $ a< b$ two real numbers and consider the multiple integral:
$$I = \int_{a}^{b}dx_{1}\int_{a}^{x_{1}}dx_{2}\cdots \int_{a}^{x_{i-1}}dx_{i}\int_{x_{i+1}}^{x_{i}}dx \int_{a}^{x_{i}}dx_{i+1}\cdots \int_{a}^{x_{n-2}}x_{n-1}$$
where $n \ge 1$ and $i \in \{0,...,n-1\}$. In the above, I am identifying $x_{0} = b$ and $x_{n}=a$. There is a little asymmetry in the above because there is this variable $x$ which is integrated from$x_{i+1}$ to $x_{i}$ and I would like to make it my $n$-th variable $x_{n}$. I would obtain the solution of my problem if the following equality holds:
$$I = \int_{a}^{b}dx_{1}\int_{a}^{x_{1}}dx_{2}\cdots \int_{a}^{x_{n-2}}dx_{n-1}\int_{a}^{x_{n-1}}dx_{n}.$$

However, I've been trying to prove this equality for hours but got nowhere. Any help is appretiated!

Comment: Try writing the integral with indicators by collapsing all variable bounds into indicators. Then see if it yields the identity.